# DDEV 403 Forbidden on provided URL with ddev start or ddev launch (docroot wrong)

Tags: typo3, ddev

I'm not experienced with ddev docker,
i have installed a client website on my local windows computer.
I have installed docker
installed ddev
i have copied the client config.yaml on the root folder/ of my website.
i have imported also the db.
my ddev start on my cli console:

```
ddev start
...
Creating ddev-router ... done

Project type has no settings paths configured, so not creating settings file.
Restarted client-website-name

Your project can be reached at https://client-website-name.ddev.site https://127.0.0.1:55023.(1)
```

but this link give an "403 Forbidden" error.
new update:
my typo3 src and typo3conf folders are under a subfolder named "public".
So when i type https://client-website-name.ddev.site/public/ it guide me throught a new install "The Installation Wizard".

I'm new to ddev so i read the documentation but i didn't find where i can see this url->(1) installed ?
How i cna change and manipulate this so i get my website running.

I'm using Win 10.

All docker containers web, db,.. seems running fine.

Comment: Assuming that you use Apache, find its configuration file for virtual hosts and fix `DicumentRoot` by adding `public` folder to the path. Check Docker's documentation to find configs location according to your setup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common reason for a 403 in ddev is that there is no index.php (or index.html) in the configured docroot.

1. Figure out where your docroot is (where the index.php is). On a composer-installed TYPO3, this is most likely the "public" directory.
2. In the project's .ddev/config.yaml, set docroot correctly, probably `docroot: public` or `docroot: web` or something like that.
3. `ddev restart`

See [DDEV FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/faq/#why-do-i-get-a-403-or-404-on-my-project-after-ddev-launch) .

Comment: Thanks this solution save my day !

Comment: Happened to me after I checked out the git repository which contained some versioned symlinks, which of course were faulty on my system. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One reason in TYPO3 v12 might be that you use an old extension that has still something like this in some PHP file(s) noted:

```
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die('Access denied.');
```

This has to be changed to:

```
defined('TYPO3') || die('Access denied.');
```

It might not be expected perhaps but those files can even block the command `vendor/bin/typo3` with the confusing error message:

> Access denied.user@domain-web:/var/www/html$ vendor/bin/typo3 cache:flush

`user` and `domain` vary depending on your configuration.

Usually the old notation will perhaps still exist when an extension shall be updated by a developer, common users shouldn't have to check extensions if those are already marked as compatible to TYPO3 v12.